# Check if page refreshed or not In Perl or Jquery

Tags: jquery, perl, mason

In my project I am saving some data on the click of  button. After saving that I am redirecting the user to a new page.

Now after redirecting to the new page, I want to check whether the user has refreshed the page and if they have refreshed, show an alert that the page has been refreshed.

How can we do this in **Perl**?

Comment: `whether the user has refreshed the page or if refreshed i am` - Sorry, but...What?

Comment: He means "if the page has been refreshed show an alert". However, the purpose of redirecting to a new page is so that a refresh is non toxic. Is there some other logic going on you're trying to avoid repeating?

Comment: i am saving some values in the database that is autoincremented

Comment: the data is getting saved multiple time with auto incremented value...so this is the problem